# Can I create a module including only a helper class?

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Is it possible to create a module/extension with only a Helper class declared?
I am trying to create a module because I need to use a function on more than one phtml files.

So far I got this code:

**/app/etc/modules/Mycompanyname_CategoryStep.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompanyname_CategoryStep>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompanyname_CategoryStep>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Mycompanyname/CategoryStep/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class Mycompanyname_CategoryStep_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function add($num1, $num2)
    {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}
```

**/app/code/local/Mycompanyname/CategoryStep/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompanyname_CategoryStep>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompanyname_CategoryStep>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <categorystep>
                <class>Mycompanyname_CategoryStep_Helper</class>
            </categorystep>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

That's the error I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Categorystep_Helper_Data' not found in 
>   /home/account/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 550

Am I missing something? I followed [this](http://magenticians.com/create-magento-custom-module/) guide to create the module and [this](https://magenticians.com/create-helper-magento/) guide and several others to create the Helper class. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have done spelling mistake or there some issues with upper and lower case char linux is case sensitive so check spelling and lower and upper case character is properly used.

Comment: Good to hear that you have resolved your issue. +1 for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You need to create module xml in

in `app/etc/modules/Mycompanyname_Categorystep.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompanyname_Categorystep>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompanyname_Categorystep>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Then for module main config create `app/code/local/Mycompanyname/Categorystep/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycompanyname_Categorystep>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompanyname_Categorystep>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <categorystep>
        <class>Mycompanyname_Categorystep_Helper</class>
      </categorystep>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

then your helper `app/code/local/Mycompanyname/Categorystep/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class Mycompanyname_Categorystep_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    //Your code here
}
```

The thing is, in Magento 1.9 module name's first letter should capital, but not all other. So you need to use **Categorystep** instead of **CategoryStep**

Comment: That was driving me crazy! Thank you for your help. It is indeed working fine now.